# Select multiple overlapping islands in UV Editor?

Tags: uv, shortcut, selection-tools

I want to select multiple overlapping islands all at once in UV Editing mode. 3dsmax can do this by clicking and dragging a window around my element, but I couldn't find a comparable function in Blender. Not being able to select in UV Editing by clicking and dragging a window is a huge missing feature, or I am not sure how to find it :/

See below:

[image]

I want to select the islands corresponding to the fan in the editor, which are around 12. I got them to overlap, but cannot select all of them at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Box select*, which is activated with <kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

You can also use <kbd>C</kbd> for *Circle Select* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> for *Lasso Select*.

For more on selection tools in the *UV editor*, see [the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Layout_Editing#Selecting_UVs).

Comment: Ah, thats it! Couldn't have figured it out on my own! Thanks!

Comment: @SyedImran Do you mind to pick this one as the answer by clicking on the **√** icon on the left?